# Easiest way to create this using CSS

Tags: css

Does anyone know the most elegant way of creating text as below. Obviously the numbers will change so the widths for both numbers need to be dynamic. I've tried a few different methods the solution I came up with seems excessively complicated for something that should be easy.

[image: What i'm trying to create]

My current solution:

```html
<span style="height: 20px; font-size: 20px;">12,312,213,213</span>
<span style="position: relative; display: inline-block; width: 70px; height: 20px;">
                <span style="position: absolute; top: -2px; left: 0; height: 16px; font-size: 12px; line-height: 12px; background-color: #be3ad1; padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px; border-radius: 3px; color: white;">
                    12,321,321
                </span>
</span>
```

Comment: With what HTML? What CSS did you try? Where - and *how* - did it fail? Please read both the "*[mcve]*" and "*[ask]*" guidelines.

Comment: With CSS and HTML. I haven't failed but my solutions seem to become excessively complicated so I thought I would see what other peoples solutions are.

Comment: Please share what you have done so far.

Comment: What you are suggesting must be more complicated than it appears. My solution would be to float two divs (smaller with radius border and purple background) within a container div (grey) - each div with appropriate padding. Seems simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check My css will help you:

```css
.superscript { 
position: relative; 
top: -2.5em; 
font-size:200%;
font-weight:bold;
background-color:#BD37CC;
border-radius:12px;
padding:3px;
float:right;
}
.main{
background-color:#F2F2F2;
display:block;
padding:20px;
margin:10px;
width: 300px;
}
.textMain{
font-size:400%;
bottom: -0.5em;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
   <span class='textMain'>123,123</span>
  <span class="superscript">12,123</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you sir. That looks a lot easier than my solution